# Tor does not start under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

After unpacking the tor browser from `https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en` I cannot start it...

Here's the error message:

```
$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop --debug
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach --debug'...
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0600
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0601
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0602
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0603
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x06dd
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x070f
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2028
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2029
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfff9
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffa
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffb
./Browser/start-tor-browser: line 372: 22261 Segmentation fault TOR_CONTROL_PASSWD=${TOR_CONTROL_PASSWD} ./firefox --class "Tor Browser" -profile TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default "${@}" < /dev/null
```

When I run:

```
$ Browser/./firefox 
tor: symbol lookup error: tor: undefined symbol: evutil_secure_rng_set_urandom_device_file

$ Browser/./start-tor-browser --debug
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0600
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0601
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0602
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0603
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x06dd
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x070f
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2028
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2029
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfff9
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffa
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffb
```

Do you have any ideas why?

Update:

Here's the error from **Hardened Tor Browser**:

```
`$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop --debug
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach --debug'...
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0600
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0601
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0602
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x0603
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x06dd
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x070f
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2028
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0x2029
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfff9
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffa
Unable to update the static FcBlanks: 0xfffb
ASAN:SIGSEGV
=================================================================
==4065==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f95ffed4d16 bp 0x7ffed53ea690 sp 0x7ffed53ea628 T0)
ASAN:SIGSEGV
==4065==AddressSanitizer: while reporting a bug found another one. Ignoring.`
```

Comment: a segmentation fault is an indication of some kind of memory corruption taking place, there are many reasons it can happen. can you look at the output of the kernel log (e.g. `dmesg`) and see if there is an associated report in there of the application crashing? is this a fresh, unaltered copy? the error about "FcBlanks" suggests some kind of graphics problem but it may be unrelated.

Comment: There are no messages in the log. 
Also, standard version of Firefox works well. Memory sticks are brand new and tested. 
It's a fresh copy. The same error occurs for 6.0.2 and 6.5a1 version of Tor-Browser.

Comment: We'd need to see something like a stacktrace from a coredump, which is probably prohibitively technical if you've never done it before. Could you try running the "hardened" Tor Browser and see if ASAN (the "hardening" used) gives any useful output with the same `--debug` flag, please?

Comment: Downloaded this: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads-hardened

The error is in the initial post (couldn't fit here).

Comment: It's a NULL deref but provides no indication where or why. You say `firefox` runs okay, but what about `firefox-esr`? Also how comfortable would you be with trying to get some debugging output through gdb: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking#Usinggdb

Comment: Also are you doing anything unusual with your fonts or fontconfig? FcBlanks error stems from there and I seem to recall it causing a crash condition on OSX when someone had done some tinkering with fonts. Tor Browser uses it's own set of fonts and it's own fontconfig to create a consistent fingerprint.

Comment: It's a default fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. Everything standard and up to date. I'm pretty sure this error will show up on many more ubuntu boxes out there.

Here's gdb output: https://codeshare.io/Ctr5z

No, I haven't changed anything related to fonts.

Comment: could you add the output of the gdb command `bt full` (run after it has crashed) to that?

Comment: OK, before that unistalled ubuntu version of TOR  and installed the one from official website. Firefox now start (with dozen of errors) but nothing really works (no network, cannot change browser settings). Here's the new dump: https://codeshare.io/6ppx8

Comment: the `tor` package isn't required and shouldn't interfere with Tor Browser, the CRC match errors are weird though, is the debug file you downloaded for the same version of Tor Browser you're running?

Comment: For the gdb stuff, try without ASAN, just a stock tor browser. stick the debug file for it in place, then launch it from gdb, let it crash, then run `bt full`

Comment: I started again from the scratch, rechecked all the versions, and... it still does not work. However, the dump is different - no CRS errors: https://codeshare.io/PumJQ. `bt full` still returns 'no stack'.

Comment: That doesn't look like a crash though, it exited normally. If you run it outside of gdb does it still segfault?

Comment: Yes. Firefox only starts when in gdb. Outside gdb it crashes with seg fault.

Comment: Any more ideas?